# Strategies for exposing Solr to search engine crawlers (SEO)

Tags: jquery, json, solr, seo

I have a Solr search server that serves JSON to my web front-end which uses jQuery to fetch data based on user provided search terms and selected facets. Once the initial search results are shown (with pagination) and user clicks a result, the web front-end queries my database to fetch product detail and shows it to user. Now I am trying to figure out what's the best strategy in such a scenario to expose this internal search to SEO so that a Google user, for instance, can find the products my Solr search server is returning and be able to see the product detail? I am not sure if it is a good idea to actually allow crawlers to walk through our internal search page because it can potentially affect Solr caches and evictions (negatively?). But in that case how do I expose the product detail to the crawler that is only accessible through the search result?

(I am aware of the hashbang and SEO for AJAX so this question is about how to let a crawler discover products we are serving through Solr search server?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a sitemap

http://www.sitemaps.org/